# How to determine when to split integral when calculating area between two curves? Calculus 1

Tags: calculus

When finding the area between two curves, you have to find the integral over some interval [a, b] of 
f(x) - g(x) or f(y) - g(y). 
When finding the are between y = ${\sqrt {x+3}}$ and y = ${\sqrt {3-x}}$ over the interval [-3, 3] you have to split the integral up into two separate integrals, one from [-3, 0] and one from [0, 3].
How do you recognize this when finding the area between two curves?

Comment: In your example you should check the condition $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)\geq 0$. But when $h(x)$ has a sign change, then $\int_a^b h(x) dx$ does not represent the area between the curves and you have to split the integral in the points, where $h(x)$ has a sign change. Remember, an area can't be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Fakemistake's comment:

If $\color{red}{f(x) \ge g(x)}$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, then the area between the two curves is given by $$A = \int_a^bf(x) - g(x)\,dx$$

But your two curves do not meet that if clause. Part of the problem is linguistic. The wording here is not precise. What exactly does "area between two curves" mean in this case? One could take it to mean the area between the curves *horizontally*:

[image]

or *vertically*:

[image]

Because we are expressing these curves as functions, they probably mean the vertical version.

But the area formula holds for when one curve is always above the other. In this case, the curve on top changes at $0$. So to use that area formula, you have to break the area up into the two regions where one curve is always on top, and calculate those areas separately:

$$A = A_\text{left} + A_\text{right}\\A_\text{left} = \int_{-3}^0 \sqrt{3-x} - \sqrt{x + 3}\,dx\\A_\text{right}= \int_0^3 \sqrt{x + 3} - \sqrt{3-x}\,dx$$

Alternatively, you can express the area vertically between two curves without regard to which curve is on top by
$$A = \int_a^b |f(x) - g(x)|\, dx$$
But this differs from the above only superficially. You'll still end up calculating the integral of the absolute value in the same fashion.